# Hashicorp Vault. Kubernetes auth

Tags: kubernetes, vault

Подскажите пжлста. Прикрутил sidecar agent вольта к основному поду. Секрет норм тянется из вольта и складываются в под, по пути /vault/secrets/credentials.txt в формате

```
last_vault_rotation: 2020-12-02T12:37:20.440116271+06:00
password: <password>
rotation_period: 604800
ttl: 506735
username: <username>
```

Деплой в кубер делаем с помощью хелма. Вопрос: как сделать так чтобы под увидел креды (лежащие в файловой системе пода) и подтянул их для коннекта к бд?